# Environment variable gets quoted in iTerm / terminal from .env

Tags: node.js, macos, oh-my-zsh, iterm2, dotenv

I have a `.env` file like this:

```sh
SOME_SECRET="84158be5-a644-4cd9-9350-5ec24efc67e9"
```

Now I'm installing `dotenv`:

```sh
npm install -g dotenv-cli
```

When running `dotenv -p SOME_SECRET` in iTerm2, I get this output:

```sh
dotenv -p SOME_SECRET
"84158be5-a644-4cd9-9350-5ec24efc67e9"
```

When doing the same in VS Code terminal, I get this output:

```sh
dotenv -p SOME_SECRET
84158be5-a644-4cd9-9350-5ec24efc67e9
```

The VS Code output (without quotes) is the expected one.

Trying the same on another machine (macOS Big Sur as well), the iTerm output is the same as in VS Code.

Back on the first machine, when running macOS Terminal, it shows the same behavior as iTerm2 - so it seems related to the `zsh` settings I guess. On the other hand, when changing the Terminal to "external" in VS Code according to the screenshot, it still shows the expected output:

[image]

What might cause this behavior?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it: my `.zshrc` did contain this entry:

```sh
source ~/.dotenv.sh
```

`~/dotenv.sh` has this content:

```sh
cd()
{
    debug()
    {
        if [ $DOTENVSH_DEBUG = true ]; then
            echo $1
        fi
    }

    loadenv()
    {
        debug "Loading $1"
        for i in $(cat $1); do
            export $i
        done
    }

    builtin cd $@
    ERR=$?

    if [ $ERR -ne 0 ]; then; return $ERR; fi

    if [ -e .env ]; then
        loadenv .env
    fi
}%
```